# ARKit insideFrustumOf ambiguous result

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I want to show navigation guide(tell user to move left or right if node is not visible). And for this I am using this code sninppet to check if node is present in camera or not

```
renderer.isNode(pathNode, insideFrustumOf: navigationNode)
```

Most of the times, it is working fine, but when object/node is on the ground(i.e. near foot or even little behind your foot) and not visible in camera, it still returns true. Is there anything I am missing or Anything can be done to make experience better?

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging, I found out its the 3rd party [library](https://github.com/maxxfrazer/ARKit-SCNPath) I am using for creating custom geometry scene node is at fault, Function works well.